# How to call function from common helper outside application folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to call a function in core php file from a common_helper.php file which is in application/helpers folder of codeigniter. The function which is wrtten in helper file is used in member controller also . So in codeigniter site this is working. But not in core php which is outside.Please help me

File structure:

project/Test.php

application/controllers/Member

application/helpers/common_helper.php

here is my common_helper.php

```
function reg_code()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    echo "in registration_code";
    $registration_code = get_reg_code();
    return $registration_code;
}

function check_code($registration_code)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership WHERE reg_code = '$registration_code'";
    $query = $CI->db->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}

function get_reg_code()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('string');
    $alha_result = random_string('alpha',1);
    $numeric_result = random_string('numeric',3);
    $reg_code = $alha_result.$numeric_result;
    $reg_code = strtoupper($reg_code);

    //check if code exists
    if(check_code($reg_code)){
        return $reg_code;
    }else{
        get_reg_code();
    }
    return $reg_code;
}
```

Test.php

```
include_once "../application/helpers/common_helper.php";
$reg = reg_code();
echo "Reg Code :".$reg;
```

Comment: First check if your file `common_helper.php` is loaded...

Comment: Yes its loaded coz in that i have email function which is being called. Even echo in those function works. But i guess fordb access there is something which i a not aware off .@Praveen

Answer (score 0):

You use $CI = & get_instance(); in your helper functions
after this call there is main framework class object in that $CI variable, that's why when you use it in Controller everything work. But when you use it inside core php file, you don't initialize framework classes, so method call get_instance() fails and nothing work.

Comment: So what is the solution? @ Denis Alimov.

Comment: If you still want to use helper, you should initialize needed framework classes. How to do that depends on your codeigniter version, but usually it is hard task. You can look how it is done in index.php. @piya

Answer (score 0):

My Custom Helper -- (custom_helper.php)

```
<?php  

if(!function_exists('p'))
{
    function p($arr)
    {
      echo '<pre>'; 
      print_r($arr);
      echo '</pre>';
    die;
    }
}

?>
```

and then i have created i sample.php file in project root directory

sample.php --

```
<?php 

include('./application/helpers/custom_helper.php');
$arr = array('1','2','3','4');
p($arr);

?>
```

Output --

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

please use this way, it will work 100% and do not use below line in helper file using that we can access helper methods outside the application folder.

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```